# How to get CSV/XL file data in controller and put them into an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I want to make an array and into this array want to put all data from CSV/XL file which select from the file input field, like this below example which I was tried

**.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with url: home_make_array_path, multipart: true do |form| %>
    <%= form.email_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= form.file_field :file, class: 'form-control' %>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
<% end %>
```

**controller.rb**

```
def make_array
    email_list = []
    CSV.foreach(params[:file], headers: true) do |csv_row|
        email_list << csv_row['email']
    end
end
```

the above codes don't work properly!

What should I do now, please?

I am using **Rails 6**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
path = params[:file]?.path # you may need to get the tempfile path of this file field
email_list = CSV.read(path, headers: true).dig('email')
```